# how to segment the marbling/fibers on a piece of meat

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, edge-detection

I want to be able to highlight the marbling in a piece of meat like this:

[image: 1]

I'm using OpenCV (blurring, sobel operator) to detect the edges, which I was hoping would give me just the main marbling. However, I end up with a lot of noise. see example output here:

Is there a way I can reduce the noise so that I get only the marbling, and little to none of the meat? What I want is actually what shows as the black gaps in the example output as the regions of interest (like this...), but I'm not sure how to achieve that.

Please comment if further explanation is needed -- I'm new to image processing and OpenCV, so I may not be explaining this very well.

Comment: Why are the gaps (fat) black and not white as in your original image? Perhaps you need to photograph under different lighting conditions that give better contrast for the fat.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on why they need to be white instead of black -- wouldn't they be black because there are no edges detected in that region? I can try different lighting conditions, but I'd like to also know how I would achieve being able to see only the fat and the grain of the meat if possible.

Comment: Blurring and applying a gradient filter is about the best you can do to make the marbling completely invisible, when you have such a wonderful contrast !

Comment: `@dumblesore` My mistake. I overlooked that you already did canny processing. I thought your images were original unprocessed and was suggesting if not enough contrast to process under different color lighting or color filters to enhance the fat vs meat. Then ignore canny and just threshold and get contours (as suggested by @Yves Daoust) below

Comment: Please show an original unprocessed image that corresponds to your canny edge detected images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite easy to binarize the green component to separate meat from marbling by simple thresholding. Then use contouring.

[image]

Comment: Then use some morphology to remove small spots and fill in gaps as desired. Then get contours rather than canny edges. Then draw filled white contours on black background

Comment: @fmw42: notice that I already advised contouring. To get rid of small spots, discarding the very short contours is enough. I don't think that any morphological postprocessing will be needed.

Comment: `@Yves Daoust` Sorry, I read your post too quickly and missed the contour part. You are correct, you can remove small spots by contour filtering. But one might want morphology if one wanted to fill in gaps and connect regions. That might be easier with morphology than contour processing.

Comment: @fmw42: IMO, morphological processing will result in a mess.

Comment: `@Yves Daoust` OK. I will accept your recommendation. You might very well be correct. I have not experimented with that type image.